# Validate Windows Phone In-App purchase receipts

Tags: c#, xml

I'm working on a Windows Phone 8 app. My app will include in-app purchases. I'm trying to understand the receipt concept. From my understanding, after someone purchases a product inside of my app, a receipt is generated.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Receipt Version="1.0" CertificateId="{Identifier1}" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2012/store/receipt">
  <ProductReceipt PurchasePrice="${PurchaseAmount}" PurchaseDate="{DateTime}" Id="{Guid1}" AppId="{Guid2}" ProductId="{ProductName}" ProductType="Consumable" PublisherUserId="{Identifier2}" PublisherDeviceId="{Identifier3}" MicrosoftProductId="{Guid3}" />
  <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <SignedInfo>
      <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
      <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
      <Reference URI="">
        <Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" /></Transforms>
    <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
    <DigestValue>{Identifier4}</DigestValue>
      </Reference>
    </SignedInfo>

    <SignatureValue>{HashedValue}</SignatureValue>
  </Signature>
</Receipt>
```

Great! I'm not sure how to tell if this receipt came from Microsoft's servers though. Can someone explain to me how to verify that? I saw this: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/In-app-purchase-receipt-c3e0bce4 However, it doesn't make sense to me. I don't understand the certificates in the example. Is "IapReceiptProduction.cer" a set thing? Or is just for this sample?

I'm sorry if this is a dumb question.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lighthouse/archive/2013/08/28/faqs-about-in-app-purchase-for-windows-phone-8.aspx FYI

Answer (score 6):

The 'CertificateId' attribute in the 'Receipt' XML element determines which certificate was used to sign the Windows Store receipt. Once you have the CertificateID ('{Identifier1}' in your sample), you can download the required certificate from the URL specified in the code sample below as 'certificateUrl'. This is how you would download the certificate programmatically:

```
public static X509Certificate2 RetrieveCertificate(string certificateId)
{
    const int MaxCertificateSize = 10000;

    // We are attempting to retrieve the following url. The getAppReceiptAsync website at 
    // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.store.currentapp.getappreceiptasync.aspx
    // lists the following format for the certificate url.
    String certificateUrl = String.Format("https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=246509&cid={0}", certificateId);

    // Make an HTTP GET request for the certificate
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(certificateUrl);
    request.Method = "GET";

    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    // Retrieve the certificate out of the response stream
    byte[] responseBuffer = new byte[MaxCertificateSize];
    Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    int bytesRead = ReadResponseBytes(responseBuffer, resStream);

    if (bytesRead < 1)
    {
        //TODO: Handle error here
    }

    return new X509Certificate2(responseBuffer);
}
```

You can see more of this code sample [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ie/library/windows/apps/jj649137.aspx). The "IapReceiptProduction.cer" is included in that sample simply to show how receipt verification works, without having to download the cert via code. Once you have the certificate, you can use the [System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.xml.signedxml(v=vs.71).aspx) API to verify the receipt, as demonstrated in the code sample you linked.