# In-App Purchases don't persist between app installations

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps

I have a question for developpers which uses Windows store in-app purchases.

I create some in-app purchase in my Win8.1 universal app to unlock(make disapear) ads in my application. I am currently testing IAP with a beta version (hidden app).

I do the following to reproduce my problem :

- install beta version of my app : I see ads
- buy license "no ads"
- confirmation that everything works as intended : no ads are displayed
- uninstall the app
- install the app again : I see ads , but I should not !

So, the app uninstallation loses all the IAP licenses bought, but for my app, they must persist between installations.

I searched a lot concerning this but to with no clear answer :

- I've read about receipts ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912720/validate-windows-phone-in-app-purchase-receipts) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lighthouse/archive/2013/08/28/faqs-about-in-app-purchase-for-windows-phone-8.aspx)) but it seems it's for Consumable IAP and not necessary for Durable IAP.
- this might be because it's a hidden (beta) app ?

Can someone confirm or refute these guesses? Must I use receipt for durable IAP, too?

Comment: @EdChum Ok sorry, I think it's more "clear" now

Comment: Still no idea what "The app looses all products precedently bought" or "IAP" is, or what you do. Try to be more specific (like steps you perform, with some message quotes), maybe also reference links. There are no telepaths here, so make no assumptions that we know anything about your situation.

Comment: Yes, I edited again, sorry, I am french and it is a very specific (windows store app) problem.

Comment: This is much better.

Comment: Voted to reopen. A few links to explain the terms (IAP, receipts, durable IAP etc, where did you "read" about receipt) would be helpful, too. The edit interface has a link to the markup help and buttons for common tasks.

Comment: Some links given by MS support that do not answser to my problem but are usefull : [link1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt148549.aspx#markets) [link2](http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/09/10/managing-hidden-apps-beta-apps-and-visibility-of-in-app-purchases-in-dev-center/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer to my question, I have contacted MS dev support, this is the answer :

"To answer your question because it is a beta the IAP is one time only so every time you uninstall and install you will be promoted to buy the IAP again. In a beta each time you reinstall the app the license data is cleared and it has to be purchases again. But once the app goes live you will not have that problem."